# Is there a way to access an external database using the force.com platform?

Tags: salesforce

My organization wants to be able to regularly read in data from an external web service which provides an ODBC interface, and update our salesforce data with that information. I've been hunting around Salesforce's documentation, and it seems like there's no way to do this except by using the Apex Data Loader's batch functionality. Unfortunately, this means that my organization would have to maintain a local computer to run the data loader nightly, which we're trying to avoid doing.

What we'd like to do is create an Apex Schedulable class or something similar and run code that can access the ODBC interface from our external data source on the salesforce platform itself. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for making outbound ODBC connections from salesforce. If the external service has an HTTP based API, then you use the http client in apex to make the api calls and get the data.

Comment: @Tneuktippa - It's pretty rare for a public web-based service to only expose an ODBC interface, are you sure it doesn't have some other interface like SOAP etc?

Comment: It's not a public web-based service, we're trying to connect to our accounting system (RentManager), which, so far as I can tell, only offers an ODBC interface.

Answer (score 1):

Outbound as mentioned you'd have to make wrap your database in a webservice. You could load the data in using data loader/Talend/Informatica/etc.